# Apache, Lighttpd, which one should I use?

Tags: apache, lighttpd

Apache has always been described to me as the solution for hosting websites, but I have been using Lighttpd for many years now and seems pretty stable. What are the advantages of Apache towards Lighttpd ? Does it scale well for heavy-usage applications ? Is it stable enough ?

Comment: This question does not invite factual answers or evaluation in its present form - the nature of the application and requests against the server are integral to comparison of the webservers' relative performance and stability. Please see our [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) and inquire on [meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/) if you are not sure why this question was closed.